# Nginx Status Page

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Does Nginx Status Page shows information all the sub-server blocks or just for that server in the location directive is embedded?

```
    location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log off;
            #allow 127.0.0.1;
            #deny all;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngx_http_stub_status_module shows status information about whole nginx server application, not particular virtual host or location.

You can view source [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_stub_status_module.c).